# Nifi: HOw to Embed ExecuteStreamCommand output to PutEmail Message

Tags: python-2.7, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi workflow as shown

[image]

the **ExecuteStreamCommand** executes Python script and produces STDOUT result to the output stream queue

[image]

Then I want to embed the result to email body which is the point where I don't know how but the email itself is sent out with no content in the body section. Below is the configuration for my **PutEmail** processor.

[image]

So, what I want to know is

1. how to embed the result to the body of the email.
2. if there is an error, will pass to **nonzero status** branch? And how can I embed error to the body of the email?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you could define body through a `message` property, however you could build it only from attribute values. And you could attach the flow file content - use `attach file = true`
2. for non-zero status the `ExecuteStreamCommand` writes the content of `stderr` to `execution.error` flow file attribute, sou use it to build message body

read more about ExecuteStreamCommand attributes: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/